# Equality between arity and degree concepts in relational theory

Tags: sql, relational-database

I've been reading the book "[SQL and Relational Theory: How to Write Accurate SQL Code](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596523068)" by C. J. Date. I have no formal background in CS, much less relational theory. Combined with the fact English is not my first language, I'm having a little trouble to understand a statement. At one moment (page 17) the author states:

> ... the number of attributes in the
>   heading is the degree (sometimes the
>   arity) ...

Does this means that the concept "degree" is equals with the concept "arity" (ie. I can use those words interchangeably) or this means that sometimes those concepts are equals (but not always)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, "degree" is equal to "-arity"; second degree is binary, third degree is ternary, etc.